# numpy.bincount and numpy.argmax function pseudocodes

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I need to make a code generation from Python to Matlab, and I'm new to Python.

Although there are some websites which give definitions of what `numpy.bincount` and what `numpy.argmax` are, they don't give a simple example which is understandable for new beginners.

There is such a statement in a Python algorithm:

```
numpy.argmax(numpy.bincount(dlabel))
```

`dlabel` is a matrix. What does this function exactly do? This calculation is very important for me, and I don't want to make rush because of misunderstanding of this simple code statement.

Could you show me example for `numpy.bincount`, and `numpy.argmax` on matrices differently, and briefly?

Comment: Have you checked their docs? There you can find some examples.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, but they showed the examples on different weird functions, which is useless for me right now. And I have to learn the other function as well in that case.

Comment: Why don't you try it out and make your own example? Also the explanation of numpy.argmax at least is quite clear "Indices of the maximum values along an axis.". Do you really need an example there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.argmax(numpy.bincount(dlabel))` returns the most common value found in `dlabel`.

To break it down, `np.bincount()` will return the count of each value in an array of non-negative integers and return an array with the count at the appropriate index (Python arrays are indexed from 0). For example:

```
>>> np.bincount([1,2,3,2,4,1,1,0])
array([1, 3, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

(So `0` appears once, `1` appears three times, ...)

`np.argmax()` returns the index of the (first) maximum value in an array.

```
>>> np.argmax(np.bincount([1,2,3,2,4,1,1,0]))
1
```

So combining the two functions, we can find that `1` appears most often in `[1,2,3,2,4,1,1,0]` (it appears 3 times).